# Subclass of subclass of Form shows up empty

Tags: c#, forms, designer, subclass

I am writing an application where I have indeterminate amount of `Forms` that require a certain popup-functionality (similar to MSN, a little window at the bottom right of the screen). I wrote the first form, then thought that I could copy the file to make a new one. So far so good. A bit later I realized that I could have subclassed Form, written my popup code, then subclassed my new `PopupForm` class to make the other forms, to simplify rewriting the popup code. So I did that, but now my forms don't show up properly in the Designer! They are completely white (no background image or controls) and I can't drag new controls onto it. I tried placing the

```
[Designer("System.Windows.Forms.Design.FormDocumentDesigner, System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", typeof(IRootDesigner))]
[DesignerCategory("Form")]
```

attributes from the `Form` class on my new form, but it didn't help. I need to be able to alter the contents of my forms, and I don't see what's wrong, so this is both annoying and confusing.

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple constructors, make sure that you call the one which calls the base parameterless constructor, i.e. the one which contains `InitializeComponent`.

```
  class BaseForm
  {
       public BaseForm()
       {
            InitializeComponent();
       }

       // not good -> does not call InitializeComponent() or :this()
       public BaseForm(int someParameter)
       { }

       public BaseForm(string someParameter)
           : this() // good -> calls InitializeComponent()
       { }

       public BaseForm(byte b)
       {
           // good -> InitializeComponent is called explicitly 
           // (but call to this() above is preferred)
           InitializeComponent();
       }
  }

  class DerivedForm : BaseForm
  {
       public DerivedForm()
          : base(5) // not good -> calls the "bad" base constructor
       { }

       // good -> base() constructor is implicitly called
       public DerivedForm(double x)
       { }

       public DerivedForm(string someParam)
          : base(someParam)  // good -> BaseForm(string) will call InitializeComponent
       { }
  }
```

Comment: This happens automatically. Whenever you instantiate an instance of a derived class, the base parameterless constructor gets called as well unless if you specify a different constructor on the base.

Comment: @BFree Yes, that's what I believed too. It must be something else.